# Transformer Design

Tags: power, transformer

I have transformer which is used for a sin-wave invert-er whose data are follows

**Primary Winding details : 250 Volt ,375 turns with 19 SWG copper .

Secondary Details       : 7.5 Volt , 11 turns with two 10 SWG  (two 10 SWG
                          parallel winded )**

Core Details : 7/2.5 inch or 43/2.5
Bobbin       : Window area 5.2 cm .,  thikness -6.7

---

I tried to Design the same on a paper and i cannot get the similar design Values and got stuck pleas help me (sorry for my Bad English)

My Design as follows

Core Area = 1.52 8 sqrt of (O/P voltage * O/P Current)

Core Area =  1.52 x Sqrt 1000VA                (not taken efficiency )
          =   48.06 cm^2

TPV = 1/4.44 * CA * Bm * F             // Bm ,flux maximum =1.3 ,Fre = 50Hz

Turn Per Volt = 1/ 4.44 * (10^-4 * 48.06) * 1.3 * 50 
              = .7290volt.

Primary winding current = (Secondary volt * Secondary Current) / primary volt
                                                           * 90% efficeancy
Primary winding current : (7.5*133.33) / (250 * .9) 
                         = 4.44 amp 
                 So 15 SWG wire taken as per table

( **but in my real transformer taken 19 SWG how ?**)

secondary current is 133 so how the copper wire select i stucked   here

primary winding area :    .7292 * 250 
                          =180.turns 
                 (but in Real transformer has 375 turns wher was i wrong ?)

secondary winding turns = 1.04 * .7292 * 7.5 
                        = 7 turns 
                   ( but in real transformer it is 10 swg or with double layer
                     11 winding)

Please help me to how to desgin are taken the transformer

Comment: "primary winding area" : you appear to be confusing turns-per-volt with volts-per-turn. For the rest of it, list the formula you're using - THEN substitute your numbers (makes it easier to see where you go wrong), then the result.

Comment: If it is cheap, they could be under-sizing the wire and running the core beyond what is typically recommended for max flux.

Comment: added the formula

Comment: I reluctantly upvoted this, even though the formulas are a mess. Please add some structure to your post and read up on how to use [LaTeX](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)-style formatting for formulas and equations.

Comment: What is real and unreal transformer? It's pretty complicated to understand, you calculate some parameters and then you ask yourself: but in real transformer....how?. Now, which transformer are you calculating and what is the question?

Comment: Mark Bursic :Sir , I am trying to find out the calculation of the real transformer which  already i have And I makes it on a  paper as design .This is  my question .

Answer (score 2):

I see: you are examing the transformer you bought and your calculations don't match. 
Volts per turn is 0.7292 V/turn. Let's ask how many turns are required for 250V? Answer is: \$N=\dfrac{250}{0.7292} \approx 343\$. The first mystery is solved.
The real transformer has 375 turns, \$\dfrac{375}{343}\cdot 1.3= 1.42\$, you are lucky, because if you buy from ebay you can get a transformer with \$B_{max}\$ at 1.9 Tesla.
The wires are too thin: maybe you have a diffent table, or they cheated on copper. If you see that the window has a lot of space left, then they cheated. If you see that window is full, then a thicker wire couldn't be used.